# How to view properties of a wallet opened with the monero-wallet-cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet

How does one view the properties of a wallet opened with the `monero-wallet-cli` to be able to change settings like `ask-password` and `refresh-from-block-height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to view the properties is the `set` command. You can access it like this:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host XMR_NODE --wallet-file WALLET_FILE \
    --password 'XXXXX' set
```

To set a property, you just run the following:

`set ask-password 0`

Comment: `help set` gives far better examples of how to set the properties as it documents the parameters as well.